# How to add select input in fullCalendar header?

Tags: reactjs, header, fullcalendar, react-bootstrap

I have created a React project using cra and using react-bootstrap. I have integrated FullCalendar to my app.

The problem is I want to add a select input to my FullCalendar header. As I have gone through the documentation there they have just shown how to add custom button to the header. I do not have any idea of how to add select input to the header.

As you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I50I.png), right now the select input is above the calendar header. I want it to bring in the header between the date title and today control buttons.

[image: screenshot of UI]

Comment: The select input displays the employees and the events related to them in the calendar.If All option is selected all the employees and there associated events are dsiplayed on the calendar.If the employee is selected by his name the events associated to that specific employees is displayed on the calendar.

Comment: There's no way to do this via the fullCalendar API unfortunately without some sort of workaround as per Mike Irving's answer, below. The only thing you can add to the header is custom buttons, currently. You'd need to use standard JS DOM manipulation functions to inject your select into fullCalendar's HTML directly. You may want to consider making / supporting a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to add support for this kind of thing in future.

Comment: First of all thank you very much to you people for giving the suggestions.Finally I acheived it actually I am using react and don't want to use jquery.So I created a custom header and set header value to false in calendar component.And I created a ref to my calendar and using it I am handling the behaviour of the calendar like next, prev, today, day week month view title heading functionality.

Comment: `don't want to use jquery`...there's no requirement to use jQuery. You can use standard JS functions if you don't want jQuery - there's always a direct replacement of one to the other, if you need it. Anyway glad you found some sort of solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution to the problem and implemented it and doing well.

I am using React library and created project using cra. So to implement the select in the header, the way I found after searching was to create our own custom header and add it to the calendar.

For doing such I have first set the headerToolbar to false in the FullCalendar component. So no header is shown and then we can add our custom header to the top before rendering the calendar component in our html. To bind the header I have created the ref to the calendar and passed it to the header.

Using the ref object we can add functionality like prev next today headerTitle day, week and month view to our header.

[image: Header image]

```
const CalendarHeader = ({calendarRef, employeeNames, employeeNameHandler, setisModalOpen}) => {
const [title, settitle] = useState(new moment().format("MMMM DD, YYYY"))

const nextHandle = () => {
    calendarRef.current._calendarApi.next()
    settitle(calendarRef.current._calendarApi.currentDataManager.data.viewTitle)
}
const prevHandle =() => {
    calendarRef.current._calendarApi.prev()
    settitle(calendarRef.current._calendarApi.currentDataManager.data.viewTitle)
}
const todayHandle = () => {
    calendarRef.current._calendarApi.today()
    settitle(calendarRef.current._calendarApi.currentDataManager.data.viewTitle)
}
const dayHandle = () => {
    calendarRef.current._calendarApi.changeView("resourceTimeGridDay")
    settitle(calendarRef.current._calendarApi.currentDataManager.data.viewTitle)
}
const weekHandle = () => {
    calendarRef.current._calendarApi.changeView("resourceTimeGridWeek")
    settitle(calendarRef.current._calendarApi.currentDataManager.data.viewTitle)
}
const monthHandle = () => {
    calendarRef.current._calendarApi.changeView("dayGridMonth")
    settitle(calendarRef.current._calendarApi.currentDataManager.data.viewTitle)
}
return (
    <div className='mb-3' style={{display: "flex",justifyContent: "space-between",alignItems: "center", width: "100%"}}>
        <ButtonGroup>
            <button className="btn-theme text-white f-12 wid-55" onClick={() => prevHandle()}>Prev</button>
            <button className="btn-theme text-white f-12 wid-55" onClick={() => todayHandle()}>Today</button>
            <button className="btn-theme text-white f-12 wid-55" onClick={() => nextHandle()}>Next</button>
        </ButtonGroup>
            
        
        <div className="fc-toolbar-chunk">
            <Form.Select size='sm' onChange={employeeNameHandler}>
                <option value="all">All</option>
                {
                    employeeNames.map((name, idx) =>
                        <option value={name} key={idx}>{name}</option>
                    )
                }
            </Form.Select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3 style={{align: "center"}} id="title">{title}</h3>
        </div>
        

        <div className="fc-toolbar-chunk">
        <ButtonGroup>
            <button className="btn-theme text-white f-12" onClick={() => setisModalOpen(true)}>Add Appointment</button>
        </ButtonGroup>
        
        </div>
        <ButtonGroup>
            <button className="btn-theme text-white f-12 wid-55" onClick={() => dayHandle()}>Day</button>
            <button className="btn-theme text-white f-12 wid-55" onClick={() => weekHandle()}>Week</button>
            <button className="btn-theme text-white f-12 wid-55" onClick={() => monthHandle()}>Month</button>
        </ButtonGroup>

    </div>
)
```

}

export default CalendarHeader

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this in `FullCalendar v5` by calling a function from `datesSet` in which I insert my `<select>` - checking first that it isn't there already, as the event could be called multiple times e.g. on view change

```
/* in your FullCalendar setup... */
datesSet(dateInfo) { // v4 datesRender(info)
    AddMySelectToFullCalendar();            
}

/* and the function it calls ... */
function AddMySelectToFullCalendar() {
    if($("select[id=mySelect]").length < 1) {
        var selectHTML =
            "<select id=\"mySelect\">" +
                "<option value="1">Option One</option>" +
                "<option value="2">Option Two</option>" +
            "</select>";
            
        // depending on where on the bar you want it, use prependTo or appendTo, and alter the array number
        $(selectHTML).appendTo($(".fc-header-toolbar .fc-toolbar-chunk")[0]);
        
        $("#mySelect").on('change', function() {
            // some onchange function
        });
    }
}
```

Previously, in `FullCalendar v3`, the same thing worked, but the insert selector was slightly different, and called from `eventAfterAllRender` i.e.

```
eventAfterAllRender: function() {
    AddMySelectToFullCalendar();    
}

// different insertion selector in function
$(selectHTML).appendTo('#myFullCalendar .fc-left');
```

Comment: There's no eventAfterAllRender in v5 (or v4). It only exists in v3 and below. https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc . It's not clear what you're referring to in terms of v5.

Comment: You are right.. I'm actually calling this in `datesSet(dateInfo)` (v5) and `datesRender(info)` (v4) .. I'll amend my answer